# TKinter window not responding in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'll get straight to the point. My TKinter window opens, but crashes immediately, displaying the `(not responding)` message. Here's my code:

```
from graphics import graphics

gui = graphics(500, 500, 'number')
text = 'no'

while text != 'yes':

    gui.clear()  # Clears window

    gui.text(0, 0, text)  # Displays text on window

    gui.update_frame(1)  # Updates window

    text = input("Insert text: ")  # Updates text object
```

Now you might be wondering what the graphics class is. Long story short, it's a python file that our teacher provided for us as an alternative for using TKinter directly, even though the file itself uses TKinter. Here are the relavant functions from that file:

```
def update(self):
    """ Does an idle task update and regular update.
    """
    self.primary.update_idletasks()
    self.primary.update()

def frame_space(self, frame_rate):
    """ Sleeps for a time that corresponds to the provided frame rate.
    """
    sleep_ms = 1.0 / float(frame_rate)
    time.sleep(sleep_ms)

# This is the update frame function in the other file.
def update_frame(self, frame_rate):
    """ Updates and sleeps.
    This should be called at the end of each iteration of a users draw loop.
    """
    self.update()
    self.frame_space(frame_rate)
```

Now, I should mention that I am using PyCharm as my IDE, and that everyone else that is using the Mu IDE is *not* facing this issue. Are there any possible edits to the `update_frame()` function that can solve this problem for the PyCharm IDE?

Comment: It will be hard to diagnose without a runnable code example. Any chance you can create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: When you say "crashes", do you really mean that it crashes, returning you to a command prompt? It seems like it ought to freeze, waiting for you to give it some input.